# SQL72015 while adding unique id column in existing table having data

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, database-project

```
ALTER TABLE [Student]
    ADD [DeptId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWID() with values
```

While I run this script through sql server management studio it runs fine. But when I publish through visual studio sql server project it gives following error.

> Warning SQL72015: The column [Student].[DeptId] on table [Student]
>   must be added, but the column has no default value and does not allow
>   NULL values. If the table contains data, the ALTER script will not
>   work. To avoid this issue you must either: add a default value to the
>   column, mark it as allowing NULL values, or enable the generation of
>   smart-defaults as a deployment option.

I tried unchecking Block incremental deployment if data loss might occur in project > properties > debug

Comment: What's in the script if you choose to generate a script instead of publish directly? (or if you analyze the generated script)

Answer (score -1):

You can find solution in the Error/Warning itself.

Possible ways to avoid it:

1) Add a default value to the column **OR** 
2) Mark it as allow NULL values **OR**
3) Delete all the data/rows from table if data is not important.

Comment: Check your connection string.